# Why would a moderator delete my answer, but not also follow through and close the question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315737/return-partialview-to-jquery-ajax-post-together-with-a-variable-indicating-wha/24315882#24315882

Since, at the time, I didn't have enough rep to comment to the effect that the post should be closed as duplicate I instead answered that the question is a dupe (it was the only tool I had available at the time).

A moderator has since deleted my answer, but didn't close the question as a duplicate.  Why?  As a moderator (I'm assuming since I'm not a moderator), wouldn't you simply take care of both issues?

Comment: A mod deleted your answer because it was not an answer to the question (or to any question at all). That does not mean that he spends the time to analyze the question and fix any other issues with it.

Comment: I would also like to know why this was a bad question?  I just wanted to know more about how moderation works. I've read some/part/most of the faqs, but since I'm a long way from there I may have not paid attention to the specifically relative parts.  Should I have worded it differently?  I think I should have left out "my".

Comment: I've also suffered at the hands of Stackoverflow moderators. Seem to be one or two sociopaths amongst them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The moderator doesn't need to know the first thing about JQuery, MVC, what that question is actually asking, what the linked question is asking, how good its answers are, etc. to know that your answer is not a valid answer to the question.  Heck, the mod doesn't need to (and quite plausibly didn't) even read the question you posted the answer to or the linked question.

That doesn't mean that he knows enough about the subject material to effectively judge if these two questions are actually duplicates of each other.  That's a matter for knowledgeable non-moderator site users who are active in the relevant tags to decide on.

Comment: This is all correct. Also, some of us tend to stop reading after "Since I don't have enough rep to commnent..."

Comment: Based on all of this, would my best course of action would have been to either ignore the question or actually answer the question (contributing to the frequently discussed trend of rep-whoring)?

Comment: @whipdancer You should ignore the question.  When you get up to 50 reputation you can flag the question as a duplicate.